# Not able to add the values to the list

Tags: java

Hi i am trying to add the values to list as show in below code. i am getting error.

```
for (String n2 : number  ) {


   List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
                if (!ARRAY.contains(number)) {
        ARRAY.add(number);
   }}
```

But getting error while adding the number in to list.

error

```
 java:271: error: no suitable method found for add(List<String>
        ARRAY.add(number);
             ^
method List.add(int,String) is not applicable
  (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method List.add(String) is not applicable
  (actual argument List<String> cannot be converted to String by method invo
```

if i use like below

```
   for (String n2 : number  ) {
  List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
  if (!ARRAY.contains(n2)) {
   Email(n2);
      ARRAY.add(n2);
  }
}
```

if i am using above. Though already email sent with value n2 again it is sending again.
For first it has to sent but for second time since it is already in array it should not sent right?

Comment: Your edit still contains the design error that the array is contained in the scope of your loop. Once the loop iteration ends, the array is lost. Check my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with your code is you are adding `number` instead of `n2`

Change the code like this

```
 List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String n2 : number  ) {
          if (!ARRAY.contains(n2)) {
              ARRAY.add(n2);
          }
       }
```

Answer (score 1):

1) ARRAY  should be outside of your for loop.

2) Replace if (!ARRAY.contains(number)) to if (!ARRAY.contains(n2 )).

Your code need to like this

```
 List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (String n2 : number  ) {
     if (!ARRAY.contains(n2 )) {
          ARRAY.add(n2);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Only Sith deal in absolutes! Seriously, read all answers, many are right!

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to add a collection - numbers into a List of Strings.
I am assuming you are trying to add n2 into ARRAY.

```
ARRAY.add(n2);
```

Comment: for (String n2 : number  ) {
          List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
      if (!ARRAY.contains(n2)) {
      Email(n2);
          ARRAY.add(n2);
      }
       }

if i am using above. Though already email sent with value n2 again it is sending again.
For first it has to sent but for second time since it is already in array it should not sent right?

Comment: The wrong thing in your code was declaration of the array inside the loop - every time a new array will be created and the if condition will never be false.

Answer (score 0):

`number` is collection of string and you are adding int `ARRAY` instead add `n2`

```
List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
   for (String n2 : number  ) {
       if (!ARRAY.contains(n2)) {
          ARRAY.add(n2);
      }
    }
```

Comment: why does he create a new `   List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();` in every loop? That code will not work,in every loop the ARRAY list will be reinitialized and n2 will never be at `ARRAY` list

Comment: @Sergio yes.. it is. but my answer is to its question and related error only.

Comment: @SergioMartinez.. What will be good option to use so that data in array will not be reinitialized

Comment: @user3375647 use Prabhakaran solution, is the correct one and check it as correct

Comment: @user3375647 use prabhkaran solution not mine..some people will happy

Comment: @SanjayRajjadi your solution was wrong, and prabhkaran solution was the correct one before yours, It is fair I think...

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid there is a bit more wrong with your code than just that one error. As has been pointed out many times, you are trying to add an iterable collection of strings, `number` to your `Array` rather than `n2` which is the iteration variable. If you want to add complete `Collection` instances you can do so using `addAll()`.

As for the rest, I strongly recommend sticking to the Java naming convention and using lower case names for your variables. This will improve readability as many members of the community stick with that convention. You can find a neat write-up [here](http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm).

You also seem to, unless your code is highly simplified, make the mistake of declaring an `ArrayList` inside the scope of a loop. you are instantiating a new `ArrayList` every time you enter the loop. I am not sure that is what you want to do. Be sure to check your design.

Also, if you simply want to avoid having duplicate values, I would suggest using `Set` as it performs the check automatically using the `hashCode()` of each member on insertion to check for collisions. Try doing:

```
HashSet<String> uniqueSet = new HashSet<>(number);
```

You should now have a `Collection` of unique strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String n2 : number  ) {
    if (!ARRAY.contains(n2)) {
        ARRAY.add(n2);
    }
}

List<String> ARRAY  = new ArrayList<String>(); //have this out of the thread
```